# Sagemaker Notebook Enable Multi-Users (Git Repository)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

We have Sagemaker notebook created off a Glue development endpoint. We will be using the Sagemaker notebook as part of ETL development and testing. We would like for engineers to be able to share/collaborate on similar notebooks. For a single notebook, we were able to add a git repository (Github) using PAT (personal access token). Here are my questions:

- In the GitHub repo, commits are labeled as being created by the user "EC2 Default User". Although, I was able to modify this using git config commands, I want to understand how can other engineers use the same notebook and pass their credentials through in the commit without having to modify this config each time?

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

- Currently, the Git repository attached the notebook has my username and PAT. I would like for others to be able to use the same notebook but not authenticate to Github with my PAT. Is this an oversight in Sagemaker? How can I create an environment that facilitates for collaboration among the engineers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SageMaker Studio and Git Integration which supports is designed to help collaboration and reproducibility?

Checkout the blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-now-support-git-integration-for-increased-persistence-collaboration-and-reproducibility/)